# Server/Client token storing mechanism

Tags: encryption

We have an iOS/Android app communicating with a central database.

Each account created from the app, has an associated private key stored there, used to encrypt some private info needs to be stored in the server.

When the user creates an account on device (A), and then login from their other device (B), they fetch the data, it’s encrypted with a token stored in device (A). Then it can’t be decrypted.

We thought of storing the private key on other server maybe, but that makes it fragile, and the whole point is security is number 1 for our users.

Then, we thought of having a formula for generating a token, but that’s also fragile and can be leaked.

Although I think this problem is obviously a lot did face before, but we’re looking for solutions that fits our banking business.

*-- Edit(1) --*

So, my **Question** is:

When the user login from a different device, how can we decrypt the data fetched from the server? *Knowing that the encryption key is stored locally on the first device.*

**Goal** is:

Use a single encryption/decryption token across the user's devices.

**Constraints** are:

1. We don't want to store the token in the server.
2. We don't want to use a formula to generate that token.

Comment: What is your question? What is your goal? Constraints?

Comment: @schroeder Please check the new edit.